# cascade deleting thru trigger

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have :

1. a table "Projects" with PK ID
2. a table "Zones" with PK ID and FK ProjectID
3. a table "Cals" with PK ID and FK ZoneID
4. Trigger:

   ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[DeleteProject]
   ON [dbo].[Projects]
    INSTEAD OF DELETE
     AS 
     DECLARE @ProjectID int
     SELECT @ProjectID = deleted.ID FROM deleted

   DELETE Zones WHERE ProjectID = @ProjectID

   DELETE Projects
        FROM DELETED D
        INNER JOIN Projects T ON T.ID = D.ID
5. Trigger:

   ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[DeleteZone]
   ON [dbo].[Zones]
    INSTEAD OF DELETE
     AS 
     DECLARE @ZoneID int
     SELECT @ZoneID = deleted.ID FROM deleted

   DELETE Cals WHERE ZoneID = @ZoneID

   DELETE [Zones]
        FROM DELETED D
        INNER JOIN [Zones] T ON T.ID = D.ID

Usually it works and works fine, but I get an error

> {"The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint
>   \"FK_Cals_Zones\". The conflict occurred in database \"PlasmaAir\",
>   table \"dbo.Cals\", column 'ZoneID'.\r\nThe statement has been
>   terminated."}

when
1. Zones has 2 records for the same ProjectID
2. Calc has at least one record with ZoneID from #1

Why it happens and how to solve it?

Comment: First things first, your trigger is badly designed.YOu can never assume there wil be only one record in the inserted or deleted tables, so setting a value from one of them to a scalar variable means that the trigger needs a rewrite.

Comment: You seem to have the misconception that triggers fire once per row. In sql server triggers fire once per operation. Triggers in sql server MUST be set based or you run into all sorts of problems.

Comment: ok, how is correct. Let's see on first trigger. Row is deleting and this trigger is called. Then value of deleting project id is set to @ProjectID. Then deleting all zones (i.e. 2 zones), linked to this ProjectID. Each of deleting zones operation calls second trigger (independent of each other). Is it incorrect understanding of trigger working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that your delete had more than one record. Your trigger only deletes the first one from CALS but all of them from Zones and some of them are still in CALS.

Suppose when you delete a project it has three zone records. Your first trigger code tries to delete all there but hits an instead of trigger. This one selects only one of those records to delete from CAL.  Then it tries to delete everything in the deleted table (which are three records not one) and one or more of those has a record in CAL so you hit the FK constraint and the delete fails.

You need to make both triggers completely set based and remove all references to any scalar variables that pull data from the deleted table. They do not belong in trigger in SQL server, ever.

Comment: really Cals has only one record (for first Zone, second Zone does not have it). But no matter. Imagine, that Cals has 2 records too. Seems, I don't understand logic of triggers exactly. I thought, that trigger delete cascade too. Call "parent" trigger and remove current records then it calls child triggers etc, etc, etc